# Why has my root password changed after I updated MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0?

Tags: mysql, upgrade, password

I have set my root account passwords like this:

```
mysql -u root
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('pswd1');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('pswd2');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('pswd3');
```

I had `MySQL 5.6.47` Then I updated to `5.7.31` and everything was ok. Then I updated to `8.0.21` and immediately faced with 2 problems:

1. MySQL wouldn't start but end up with `1053` error. The problem was in missing Visual C++ Redistributable `dll` file.
2. In order to login into my root account I have to type the `pswd3` password which had been set for the 'root'@'::1' account. `pswd1` and `pswd2` won't work anymore.

What may be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL changed the default

If you chosen

> Use Strong Password Encryption for Authentication (RECOMMENDED)

mysql 8.x uses the new authentication based on improved, stronger SHA256-based password methods.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/server-authentication-method.html

when you and your apps don't support it, you have to choose the legacy mode

But you can use user with the old authentficationwhen you use

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
```

You have to add native password to all your  roo

`'root'@'::1'`   refers ipv6 localhost

'root'@'127.0.0.1'
And
'root'@'localhost'  zto ip V4

As you connect via 1pv6 change this apsword as well but use 'root'@'::1'`

localhoszt and 127.0.0.1 only work on a computer itself not over a network

how you can bind  the server to ipv4 or ipv6 is described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html

And as last poit see upgrade instructions in mysql, you can't only exchange the exe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html

Comment: I didn't choose _Use Strong Password Encryption for Authentication (RECOMMENDED)_ because I installed MySQL using a noinstall ZIP Archive. My previous question [How can I login to MySQL as 127.0.0.1 or ::1 instead of localhost?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275102/how-can-i-login-to-mysql-as-127-0-0-1-or-1-instead-of-localhost) is connected with this one. _ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';_ didn't work for me. How can I choose the legacy mode?

Comment: If you didn't use the installer, it uses the default password as described. what error message do you get, this works usually everywhere, workbench pjymyadmion mysql client...

Comment: If login into my root account with the password I'd set for 'root'@'::1' then everything is ok. But when I try to login with passwords I'd set for 'root'@'localhost' and 'root'@'127.0.0.1' accounts I get: _ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)_.

Comment: I can't follow you i never get exit

Comment: _I can't follow you i never get exit_ - sorry, I posted this by mistake and was editing.

Comment: After _ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';_ I don't get eny error messages. I get this: _Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)_.

Comment: then it has worked. you can now connect with python, php for example, that still not shs256support

Comment: I can't login into my root account with the password I set there. Still only the one for `'root'@'::1'` works for me. I use MySQL as databases for my Jira Software.

Comment: i added soe more explanation

Comment: But why did my `'root'@'localhost'` (IPv4) password changed to `'root'@'::1'` (IPv6) password? Why do I need to use the password for the `'root'@'::1'` account now?

Comment: When I added `bind-address=127.0.0.1` to the `my.ini` file now to login I have to use the password for my `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` which is good. But when I tried `bind-adress=localhost` nothing has changed. Is there a way to switch back to the password I'd set for `'root'@'localhost'` as it was before I updated MySQL? I didn't get that one: _And as last poit see upgrade instructions in mysql, you can't only exchange the exe_